# Dragging the range of a RangeSlider

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2, rangeslider

In my Qt project for viewing logfiles with charts, I need a range slider for easy navigation on the time axis.

What I need is support for dragging both handles; when clicking and dragingg in between the handles, both handles are moved together. The behaviour of the [RangeSlider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-rangeslider.html) is to position the nearest handle to the clicked position, and I cant find any way of changing this from any properties.

When the provided controls is not providing the required functionality, I wonder if the only approach is to create a new component from scratch, or if there is any way of customizing the existing controls?

Comment: Your requirement is that if you press in the space between the handles both and drag with the mouse then both handles should move. I am right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. The distance(range between lower and upper) remainds.

Comment: suppose that what you require works so we move to the right and the right handler is the maximum position and still dragging the mouse what should happen with the left handle?

Comment: It should stop if one of the handles is at end, and dragging is on the range. Then the other handle can be adjusted only if its clicked directly or diection of drag on the range goes the opposite way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is certainly possible:

```
RangeSlider {
    id: sli
    width: 300
    from: 0
    to: 1000
    first.value: 300
    second.value: 700
    Rectangle {
      anchors.left: sli.first.handle.right
      anchors.right: sli.second.handle.left
      anchors.verticalCenter: sli.verticalCenter
      height: sli.first.handle.height
      color: "red"
      MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        property real dx: 0
        onPressed: dx = mouseX
        onPositionChanged: {
          var d = ((mouseX - dx) / sli.width) * Math.abs(sli.to - sli.from)
          if ((d + sli.first.value) < sli.from) d = sli.from - sli.first.value
          if ((d + sli.second.value) > sli.to) d = sli.to - sli.second.value
          sli.first.value += d
          sli.second.value += d
          dx = mouseX
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The red rectangle is actually redundant, I merely put it there as a visual aid.

Comment: Thanks for showing a possible solution and how to do it on existing quick controls. I works, just that it is rather erratic when sliding the range. Hoping to adjust this to work  a little smoother.

Comment: Solved the problem with the erratic behaviour, just by removing the rectangle, and changing the Mousearea anchoring as was setup for the rectangel, Thanks :)